# Java import from XML to jTable

Tags: java, xml, swing

I want to import XML to jTable.
I create the form but the table is not field with the xml data  the code is with no error.

Here is my code:

```
 private void Tabela() {                          
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
try{
 DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("testxml.xml");

    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

    NodeList nodelist1 = root.getChildNodes();

    String[] st = new String[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < nodelist1.getLength(); i++)
    {
        Node node = nodelist1.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == node.ENTITY_NODE) {
            st[0] = node.getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent();
            st[1] = node.getChildNodes().item(3).getTextContent();
            st[2] = node.getChildNodes().item(5).getTextContent();
            st[3] = node.getChildNodes().item(7).getTextContent();
            ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).addRow(st);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.print("error");
}
}
```

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <note> 
    <to>Tove</to> 
    <from>Jani</from> 
    <heading>Reminder</heading> 
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> 
  </note>
```

When I am run my program the table is empty.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <note>
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
       <heading>Reminder</heading>
       <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
   </note>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) You need to check if the node is `ELEMENT_NODE`. Use `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` , not the instance's. Entity nodes are nodes representing entities in DTD for example.

b) You are assigning a single string value to all elements in `st`. You need to first collect them and then assign to your array. Best way is to collect them in a list.

c) Always print the stack trace in catch block. Otherwise you won't know what and where is the exception coming from.

Your code should look like :

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try
        {
            DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse("testxml.xml");

            Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

            NodeList nodelist1 = root.getChildNodes();

            String[] st = null;
            List<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodelist1.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node node = nodelist1.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) 
                {
                    texts.add( node.getTextContent() );

                }
            }

            st = texts.toArray( new String[]{} );


            System.out.println( Arrays.toString( st ) );

            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

            model.addRow(  st );

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("error");
        }
```